# Sitecore template field source pulling from two paths?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

In our Sitecore site, which I inherited last year, we have a content item for displaying rss fields that pulls from a path and grabs content items from within that path.  We have a few of these, and now they want to have an additional feed that pulls from all of the locations. The field a Template Source field and it says it can take a Sitecore query.  I'm trying to create a query that would pull items from more than one path, but when I use and it tells me the resulting feed is empty.  I cannot seem to find any reference online that has an example of a query that pulls from two completely separate locations.  When I try to use the content root and specify a filter of the template name or id, it also doesn't seem to work...

Just some examples of what I've tried:

/sitecore/content/Home/**[@templatename='News Article'] (empty)

query: /sitecore/content/Home/**[@templatename='News Article'] (feed is not configured properly)

/sitecore/content/Home/Health/HArticles and  /sitecore/content/Home/About/MediaCenter/News/Archives (empty)

query:/sitecore/content/Home/Health/HArticles and  query:/sitecore/content/Home/About/MediaCenter/News/Archives (invalid lookup source)

query:(/sitecore/content/Home/Health/HArticles and  query:/sitecore/content/Home/About/MediaCenter/News/Archives) (invalid lookup source)

query:(/sitecore/content/Home/Health/HArticles/* and  query:/sitecore/content/Home/About/MediaCenter/News/Archives/*) (invalid lookup source)

query:(/sitecore/content/Home/Health/HArticles/** and  query:/sitecore/content/Home/About/MediaCenter/News/Archives/**) (invalid lookup source)

/sitecore/content/Home/Health/HArticles/* and /sitecore/content/Home/About/MediaCenter/News/Archives/* (empty)

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the query to work via specifying the template name: query:/sitecore/content/Home//*[@@TemplateName='News Article']